# Saving to XML using CS & ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am coding an ASP site in Visual Studio and I can't workout how I can identify the elements in my XML tree.

```
<layerone>
    <layertwo>
        <layerthree>
          <fullName>XXXX</fullName>
        </layerthree>
        <layerthree>
          <fullName>YYYY</fullName>
        </layerthree>
        <layerthree>
          <fullName>ZZZZ</fullName>
        </layerthree>
    </layertwo>
</layerone>
```

All I need to do is save some basic data from my ASP form to the XML, I am using C# and while I can get this to write to the XML if I remove layerone, I can't workout what I need to add in to get this to write when I have 3 layers.

The part of my C# for this looks like below.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName.Text))
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath(xmlpath);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        XElement root = new XElement("layerthree");
        root.Add(new XElement("fullName", post_id.Text));
        doc.Element("layertwo").Add(root);
        doc.Save(path);
        fillGrid();
        clear();
    }
}
```

I can post more code if needed, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The structure seems clear - add a `layerone` element. To that element add a `layertwo` element, to that add a `layerthree` and to that, a `fileName`. That's not the structure in your code though. What does the *original* file contain? Your code assumes `layertwo` already exists

Comment: I've adjusted the XML example, records sit in that layerthree

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, can you please post an example of how should be the resulting XML file and how the XML is being saved with the actual code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void Main()
{
var path = @"<layerone>
<layertwo>
<layerthree>
  <fullName>XXXX</fullName>
</layerthree>
<layerthree>
  <fullName>YYYY</fullName>
</layerthree>
<layerthree>
  <fullName>ZZZZ</fullName>
</layerthree>
</layertwo>
</layerone>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(path);
XElement root = new XElement("layerthree");
root.Add(new XElement("fullName", "Test User"));
doc.Element("layerone").Element("layertwo").Add(root);
doc.Save(Console.Out);
}
```

Comment: Just adjust the code accordingly to load your xml file. Enjoy